# How to add a summary entry in each section of a table view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to summary entry in section and display result in header like this picture

[image: screenshot]

I try to read in document and tutorial but not found.

Comment: Core Data is incidental here.

Answer (score 1):

Read [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and use

> - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

And here build your own custom view for header.